# Can I get exact Visual Studio version through MSBuild property?

Tags: visual-studio

The VisualStudioVersion property returns the overall version (i.e. 12), but I need the exact version, as shown in the About dialog:

[image: Visual Studio About Dialog]

Thanks!

Comment: If i remember correctly MSBuild is not directly a part of visual studio but a part of the .net SDK and there for it will not be able to return the version of the visual studio installation. Mayby you could vind a file in the programs files folder which contains the version number

Answer (score 0):

Try this `Console.Write(typeof(string).Assembly.ImageRuntimeVersion);`